twig error: Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" ("end of statement block" expected)
I am attempting to take all of the start dates of my coworkers and calculate a total # of years of experience.  However I am getting the following error
Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" ("end of statement block" expected). in Twig\TokenStream->expect() (line 44 
{% if title %}
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
{% endif %}

{% set total_seconds = 0 %} {# Initialize a variable to store the total seconds #}

{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class ? 'views-row',
    ]
  %}

  {# Assuming 'row.content' contains a date field named 'field_start_date' #}
  {% set date_str = row.content['#view'].style_plugin.getField(row_index, 'field_start_date') %}

  {% if date_str %}
    {% set today = date('now') %}
    {% set date_object = date(date_str) %}

    {# Calculate the difference in seconds using Drupal's date formatter service with createAttribute for options #}
    {% set options = create_attribute() %}
    {% set options = options.setAttribute('granularity', 1) %} 
    {% set diff_seconds = Drupal::service('date.formatter')->formatDiff(date_object.getTimestamp(), today.getTimestamp(), 'en', options) %}

    {% set total_seconds = total_seconds + diff_seconds %} {# Add the calculated seconds to the total #}

    <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
      {{- row.content -}}
    </div>
  {% else %}
    <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
      {{- row.content -}}
    </div>
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}

{% if total_seconds > 0 %}
  {% set total_years = (total_seconds / (365 * 24 * 60 * 60))|round(2) %} {# Convert seconds to years and round #}
  <p>Total combined years since all dates: {{ total_years }}</p> {# Display the final result #}
{% endif %}

commenting out this line   {#% set diff_seconds = Drupal::service('date.formatter')->formatDiff(date_object.getTimestamp(), today.getTimestamp(), 'en', options) %#} removes any error, but doesn't return the single value that I am expecting.

Got past the error by rewriting the offending line. Still not giving the results I want but that is another issue.
    {% if title %}
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
{% endif %}


{% set total_seconds = 0 %} {# Initialize a variable to store the total seconds #}

{% for row in rows %}
  {# ... (Code to set row_classes remains the same) ... #}

  {# Assuming 'row.content' contains a date field named 'field_start_date' #}
  {% set date_str = row.content['#view'].style_plugin.getField(row_index, 'field_start_date') %}

  {% if date_str %}
    {% set today = date('now') %}

    {# Calculate the difference in seconds using Twig's date and diff functions #}
    {% set diff_interval = date(date_str).diff(today) %}

    {% if diff_interval %}
      {% set diff_seconds = (diff_interval.y * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60) + 
                             (diff_interval.m * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60) +  
                             (diff_interval.d * 24 * 60 * 60) + 
                             (diff_interval.h * 60 * 60) + 
                             (diff_interval.i * 60) + 
                             diff_interval.s %}

      {% set total_seconds = total_seconds + diff_seconds %} {# Accumulate the total tenure in seconds #}
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}

  {# ... (Rendering the row content remains the same) ... #}

{% endfor %}

{# Calculate and display the total combined tenure #}
{% if total_seconds > 0 %}
  {% set total_years = (total_seconds / (365 * 24 * 60 * 60))|round(2, 'floor') %} {# Convert to years and round down #}
  <p>Total combined tenure of all employees: {{ total_years }} years</p> 
{% else %}
  <p>No employee start dates found.</p> 
{% endif %}



You should extend twig and a custom Twig\TwigFunction and move the logic to there

Please mention the issue you are facing and what's your expectation from the code?
